# MySQL: Foreign key constraint getting ignored in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am creating a table called fac_master which has a foreign key which refers to dept_id of dept_master. The table is getting created but foreign key is not getting enforced on this table. I also have a foreign key in dept_master which works very well but not for this table.

```
create table Dept_Master
(   dept_id smallint unsigned auto_increment not null comment 'Department/Branch ID',
    dept_name varchar(100) not null comment 'Department Name such as Computer Engineering',
    prog_id tinyint unsigned not null comment 'Program ID under which this department falls',
    PRIMARY KEY(dept_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_dept FOREIGN KEY(prog_id) REFERENCES Prog_Master(prog_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE latin1_general_ci;


create table Fac_Master
(   fac_id smallint unsigned auto_increment not null comment 'Faculty ID',
    dept_id smallint unsigned not null comment 'Department Id of the department in which this faculty works',
    fac_name varchar(30) not null comment 'Name of the Faculty',
    fac_father_name varchar(30) comment 'Father\'s name of the faculty',
    fac_surname varchar(30) comment 'Surname of the faculty',
    fac_designation varchar(30) not null comment 'Designation of the faculty',
    fac_mail_id varchar(50) comment 'E-mail id of the faculty',
    fac_mobile bigint(10) unsigned comment 'Mobile number of the faculty',
    fac_address varchar(100) comment 'Permanent Address of the faculty',
    fac_status varchar(1) not null comment 'Status of Faculty: A=Active D=Deactive',
    fac_joining_date date comment 'Joining Date of the Faculty',
    PRIMARY KEY(fac_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_faculty FOREIGN KEY(dept_id) REFERENCES Dept_Master(dept_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

When i try to add a value in "prog_id" of "dept_master" which is not present in the "prog_id" of "prog_master" then it gives fk constraint error which is fine but when i try to add a value in "dept_id" of "fac_master" which is not present in the "dept_id" of "dept_master" then it gets added but it should have given a fk constraint error.
I also checked foreign key constraint in information schema and found that foreign key constraint was not there for table fac_master. I am using WAMP Server 2.2 on windows 7 HP 64 bit version.

What is the problem? please help..

**Edit:**

```
alter table Fac_Master
add constraint fk_faculty FOREIGN KEY(dept_id) REFERENCES Dept_Master(dept_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

using alter table as shown above works but not when used with create table. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Fac_Master;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the problem is caused by the way you escape the `'` in `'Father\'s name of the faculty'`. When you change it in `'Father''s name of the faculty'`, you'll find the foreign key constraints are correctly created.

Both ways of including a single quote are correct according to the manual, so it is a bug. See [this MySQL bug ticket](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67881).

Comment: Wow. Good find. Another good reason to stick to standard SQL and not use non-standard quirks...